# React: Adding CSS classes to body tag

Tags: css, reactjs

Was wondering whether there is an easier way to add classes to the body tag.

[image]

Currently I am doing something like this in
 the MainComponent

```
const MAIN_CLASSES = [ three-col, darkTheme, blueHeader, .... etc]

class MainComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    document.body.classList.add(...MAIN_CLASSES);   
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
   document.body.classList.remove(...MAIN_CLASSES);
  }

  render() ....
}
```

Interested to know what others are doing thank you!

Comment: Can I ask why? If your React app is being rendered in a `div` that is the only element on the page then why not apply styles to the root component?

Comment: Thanks @glhrmv I managed to apply global styles to body tag using aphrodite by Khan Academy